# i don't know what @foreach in asp.net mvc 5 do

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm a newbie and i don't know what @foreach do.
this is code written by my teacher

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MaSach)
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="~/HinhAnhSP/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnhBia)" width="100" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TenSach)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.GiaBan)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.MaSach }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Add to Cart", "Add", "Cart", new { id = item.MaSach }, new {url ="" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Read this properly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` is a construct that loops over the items of a collection (actually an enumeration, but never mind that now) and repeats whatever is inside the brackets (`{`,`}`) for each of the items, assigning a variable (named `item` in this case) on each iteration of the loop.

In your case, `Model` is a collection of items (of some type you haven't shown us). So on each iteration, it'll write all the HTML code between the brackets, assigning a variable named `item` on each iteration with the contents of the current item.

So imagine `Model` was a collection of five items of type `MyType`, which is defined as:

```
class MyType {
   public string Name;
}
```

Where `Name` contains the string `Hello1` in the first item, `Hello2` in the second item, etc:

So if you do:

```
@foreach(var item in Model) { 
    <p>@(item.Name)</p>
}
```

The result once parsed will be:

```
<p>Hello1</p>
<p>Hello2</p>
<p>Hello3</p>
<p>Hello4</p>
<p>Hello5</p>
```

Comment: One thing to add: Model is defined by a `@model` declaration. For example, at the top of the file, you should see `@model IEnumerable<MyClass>` or something similar

Comment: Short answer for `what foreach does`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx